# Is global phase unknowable or irrelevant?

Tags: polarization

The E field of a photon is given by $Re\{(a_1 e^{i \phi_1}, a_2 e^{i \phi_2}) e^{i (kz-\omega t)}\}$

If we describe the system in quantum mechanics, then $(a_1 e^{i \phi_1}, a_2 e^{i \phi_2}) $ is the wavefunction.

On the one hand, I always hear that global phase is non-physical and unmeasurable.

On the other hand, the global phase dictates where in the cycle the E-field is, and so I feel we should be able to measure the global phase just by measuring the E field! If the global phase is undefined, that means the E field doesn't really oscillate, it just kind of exists.

Which is right?? Is global phase here unknowable?!

--

EDIT: Another way of stating this problem is that we can measure the E field. Say our measurement device is at $z=0$ and $t=0$. Then, our measurement of the E field tells us $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$, and thus we can determine the global phase!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classically the global phase of an electromagnetic field is measurable. This is done routinely for RF and microwave electromagnetic fields using electronics. In principle the absolute phase of optical electromagnetic fields could be measured, but it is technically challenging.

Your question is pretty confused about quantum mechanics.

- Quantum mechanically the absolute phase of the wavefunction has no physical consequence and is therefore un-measurable. What you've heard is correct.
- BUT, you claim $(a_1e^{i\phi_1}, a_2e^{i\phi_2})$ is the wavefunction when we work in quantum mechanic. This is wrong.

So the fact that we can measure the absolute phase of a classical EM field does not imply we can measure the absolute phase of a quantum wavefunction.

edit: Let me say it a different way. The question asks if global phase is unknowable. The answer is that it depends. For classical EM waves the global phase is indeed knowable. But for quantum wavefunctions it is unknowable.

edit2: If $(a_1e^{i\phi_1}, a_2e^{i\phi_2})$ is not the quantum wavefunction then what is the quantum wavefunction? My favorite reference for this is [Steck "Quantum and Atom Optics"](https://atomoptics.uoregon.edu/%7Edsteck/teaching/quantum-optics/) chapter 8. There are also many many questions on this site about the wavefunction of the photon, though I'm not sure they all have good answers.

Briefly: Suppose we have a monochromatic EM field (broadband EM fields can get tricky..). We decompose the EM field into spatial modes. Each one of these modes has a certain energy (if the mode is spatially confined) or energy flux (if the mode is unconfined and represents a travelling rather than stationary wave). This energy or energy flux is quantized. The basis states for the Hilbert space are states of fixed excitation number in each mode. A generic state in the Hilbert space is a sum of terms over all possible combinations of excitation numbers of all modes (where each term of course has its own complex amplitude).

Focus for example on a quantum state that has some number of excitations in a single mode (and no excitation in any other modes). This quantum state corresponds to a state of the electromagnetic field which has finite electric field over some finite or infinite volume of space corresponding to the shape of the corresponding spatial mode. The EM field for this state doesn't really have a well-defined phase. This is related to a so-called number-phase uncertainty relation. But if you superimpose many modes you can get a coherent state whose EM field *does* have a well-defined phase. But that well defined phase only arises as a result of the relative phases of the different terms in the total wavefunction.

Comment: If that’s not the wavefunction, then can you please tell me what the wavefunction could possibly be describing in the photon polarization experiment? What on earth is the polarization filter measuring if not the E field?

Comment: @LucasMumbo see my edits but asking about what the wavefunction of the EM field is somewhat of a broad topic and may require further learning.

Comment: Thanks so much for your edits. I’m perfectly happy with accepting that there’s a wave number-phase uncertainty which I totally forgot. This means that global phase can be learned, but of course with the effect of changing the wavefunction, so we’re not learning it in the sense I initially had in mind. Thank you!

Comment: @LucasMumbo if you found this answer useful you can vote up on it and if it answers your question you can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score -2):

Classically, global phase is very relevant. It's a Lorentz scalar:

$$ \phi = \vec k \cdot \vec x - \omega t = k^{\mu}x_{\mu} $$

so it has physical meaning. Zero field is zero field.

For a wavefunction? Not so much. No one cares if the amplitude is real or imaginary. Only relative phase matters.

Comment: even if it's irrelevant, it exists, right? because everyone says global field doesn't exist!